# Need to apply formula to certain blank cells

Tags: regex, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a formula here where it is supposed to only activate if a cell in the B column is blank and when a cell in the A column is not blank. When it does activate it takes the value in A and puts it in the blank B cell. here is the code:

```
 =IF(AND(not(isblank(A)),isblank(B)), B, A)
```

the problem I'm seeing is that I want this formula to be put on certain blank cells in the B column. is there a way for me to select all of those blanks in the B column and then add the formula to all of them at once so it doesn't mess with the cells that already have values in the B column?

Comment: =Arrayformula((IF(AND(not(isblank(A2:a10)),isblank(B2:b10)), a2:a10, b2:b10))

Comment: =IF(AND(not(isblank(A)),isblank(B)), B, A) it means it will give B (Blank) when A is not blank and B is Blank, others, it will give A. Or in another word, it will always give A, except when B is Blank and A is not Blank, it will give B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a. For Non Blank A, get A for blank B and get B for non Blank B (Result1):

```
= filter
  ( 
     IF 
     ( 
        not(isblank(A2:A)), if(isblank(B2:B),A2:A,B2:B),""
     ) 
     , max(filter(row($A$2:$B) ,$A$2:A<>""))>=row($A$2:$B)
  )
```

b. For Non Blank A, Just get A for blank B (Result2):

```
= filter
  ( 
     IF 
     ( 
        not(isblank(A2:A)), if(isblank(B2:B),A2:A,""),""
     ) 
     , max(filter(row($A$2:$B) ,$A$2:A<>""))>=row($A$2:$B)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but this seems to be really close to  what I am looking for. But is it possible to have the results  in Result 1 take the place of the cells in Test B? for instance in row 5 Result1 is TestA3, is it possible for that to replace the blank spot in B5?

Comment: It is not possible, except you use trigger on edit or on change,

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(ROW(A3:A)), "4|12|13"), 
 IF((A3:A<>"")*(B3:B=""), B3:B, A3:A), ))
```

where row 11 was skipped

[image: 0]

or inverted:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(NOT(REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(ROW(A3:A)), "11")), 
 IF((A3:A<>"")*(B3:B=""), B3:B, A3:A), ))
```

[image: 0]